# How to get file default system icon?

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter, explorer

There is a `file` , for example one for a word document ; it has a predefined icon :

[image]

So how to get the predefined icon of a file ?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Keep an array of mime type (or use the extension) to image mappings, or store it in the DB? Then fetch them as you would normally for array / DB?

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the string on '.' and get the last bit like so:

```
<?php

$extension = end(explode(".", $file));

?>
```